# I want to change SignalR Self-Host to support .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

Microsoft has code sample for SignalR Self-Host
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SignalR-self-hosted-in-6ff7e6c3

But,the sample only supports .Net Framework 4.5.

I want to change the SignalR Self-Host project to support .Net Framework 4.0

How can you change the code?

Thanks,
Jun

Comment: here is a sample can download

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SignalR-Self-Host-Sample-6da0f383

Comment: Why do you need to target  .NET Framemework 4 at all? It is no longer supported.

Comment: Hi, Pawel, I have an existing window form project which is working on framework 4.0. I just want to add the SignalR Self-Host feature into that project. I don't want to upgrade that existing project to framework 4.5. That is why I need SignalR Self-Host feature to support Framework 4 as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can still use SignalR with .Net 4.0 & VS 2010 using Install-Package,
V2 only works with .NET 4.5

`Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.2.2`

A project example based on V1 fwk 4.0 : http://www.bluelemoncode.com/2013/02/default.aspx

Comment: Hi, Roger,
Thanks!
Your provided sample is a IIS web server. (I could be wrong.) However, what I need is to create a Window Form web host on framework 4.0. Can you please help with that? Thanks!